# Boolean and switch statement-combination

Tags: java

Im working on a task and the code is free from warning-messages. When i try to run the code in the console i get the message: "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"

I have tried a several diffent combination with using the INT "oddoreven" for everything and even go for the String "Fraga". But nothing seems to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class fragor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please ask me a question!");

        int oddoreven  = input.nextInt();
        String Fraga = input.nextLine();

        boolean even = oddoreven % 2 == 0; 
        boolean odd = oddoreven % 1 == 0;
        boolean fragetecken = Fraga.endsWith("?");
        boolean utropstecken = Fraga.endsWith("!");

        int cases = 0;
        switch (cases) {
            case 1:
                fragetecken = Fraga.endsWith("?");
                even = oddoreven % 2 == 0;
                System.out.println("Yes.");
            break;

            case 2:
                fragetecken = Fraga.endsWith("?");
                odd = oddoreven % 1 == 0;
                System.out.println("No.");
            break;

            case 3:
                utropstecken = Fraga.endsWith("!");
                System.out.println("Wow.");
            break;

            default: 
                System.out.println("You allways say" +Fraga);
        }
    }
}
```

Would appreciate if someone here could help me on the way to find a solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: why do you think the code doesn't work? It prints `"You allways say" + Fraga`, just like it's supposed to do. Btw. you should definitly alter the codes formatting and spelling, both are horrible (I've already done the formatting here). If you want the code to do sth else, you should probably work assign another value to `cases` than 0.

Comment: `int cases = 0; switch (cases) {` - what do you expect?

Comment: A boolean has two possible values, true and false. Don't use two to determine oddness. If it's even it's not odd. Same for even.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's see if we can get things going for you.

The error seems to come from line 20. You are asking for:

```
System.out.println("Please ask me a question!");
int oddoreven  = input.nextInt(); // this is line 20
String Fraga = input.nextLine();`
```

Naturally, the first thing you write after the question is well, the question (hence a `String`), but in the code, the first thing you are asking for is an integer. That gives you the `InputMismatchException`.

So if you write an integer, you don't get the same exception again, which is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

you are most likely using wrong inputs.

When in your code you make:

**int oddoreven = input.nextInt();**

**String Fraga = input.nextLine();**

You are supposed to first give the input an integer value, then a string value.

What the program will do is try to parse whatever u are passing to the question:

**Please ask me a question!**

You should give him an integer value.
If you give him another value, such as "hello", the program will fail at runtime because it is trying to get a number from "hello" (Wich will be quite a difficult task ;) ).

Try to first give the program  a numerical (integer) value.